# New design: checkmarks on questions with accepted answers too hard to see

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is maybe minor, but it used to be really easy to tell if a question had an accepted answer and it's annoyingly hard now.  I guess you want the checkmark to be lighter than the text, but maybe you could 1) make both the checkmark and the green text darker, and 2) make the checkmark a little bigger or something.

Comment: [My suggestion of a circular outline instead](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/963/design-ideas-for-mathematics-site/967#967) was either not noticed or silently rejected after consideration. I don't want to harp on it, so I'm posting this here once and won't again.

Comment: I agree, though I'm happy to see the change to a consistent use of a checkmark everywhere (the triple dot triangle employed in the prior revision - besides being inconsistent - reminded me too much of a nuclear hazard sign!).

Comment: @Rahul: the problem I see with that is that, while it's visible, it's a little unclear what it means.  So not optimal from a design perspective, I guess.

Comment: I agree, the checkmark is too subtle.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the check mark all together and replaced it with a green bgcolor. Accepted answers should be a lot easier to read now.

Comment: It's still pretty faint for me, although that might just be my screen.